# Selenium IDE getting id from url parameter?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am struggling with getting the id from a url in selenium ide please could you assist me Thanks. When I echo the store location it removes the equals? PLease see the comments for the output below. Thanks for any help given.

When I run the ide tests I run it through webdriver and on internet explorer but i dont think this should make much difference.

```
<tr>
    // gets http//website.co.uk/index.php?main_detail_id=123456789123456
    <td>storeLocation</td> 
    <td>loc</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    //prints http//website.co.uk/index.php?main_detail_id123456789123456
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${loc}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    //no errors have also tried split '?'
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>"${loc}".split('=')[2]</td>
    <td>mainid</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    //prints nothing.
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${mainid}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code with help of that you can get ID from URL

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>http//website.co.uk/index.php?main_detail_id=123456789123456</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>delimiter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['test'].split('=')[storedVars['delimiter']]}</td>
    <td>vv</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${vv}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```